# Python: fastest way to define a function using a list of 2-tuples

Tags: python

Suppose L is a list of two tuples, with `len(L)~16,000`.

An element of `L` is of the form (x,y) where in my case x is itself a list of 7 elements and y is a float.

How can I define a function f such that it computes f(x)=y using `L`?  Right now I am using the naive code:

```
def f(x):  
    for i in range(0,len(L)):
        if x==L[i][0]:
           return L[i][1]
```

But this is taking way too long. Any suggestions to make this run faster?

Comment: It's called a `dict`.

Comment: Are you using lists or tuples? Not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tabulate = dict(L)
f = tabulate.get
```

This will work as long as you use tuples for your keys instead of lists.

Answer (score 2):

What you're implementing is called an association list, for example:

```
L = [ ('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3) ]
```

A far better data structure to use in Python would be a dictionary:

```
D = { 'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3 }
```

Look, you can even transform an association list into a dictionary:

```
D = dict(L)
```

Now you can quickly retrieve any value from it:

```
D['y']
=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a dict, a list of key-value pairs that you can use to do lookups, it would be perfect for your "function"

Here is an overview of the python dict datatype:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: no problem, there are many other dict tutorials on the internet, if you dont like that one, google search for python dict or python dictionary